# understanding the variable char size[] of the header tar

Tags: c, unix, tar

I try to make a function to read each headers of a .tar file on C and when i print the char size of the struct of the header it gives me "0000000016" byte for example. 
But the file is 318 byte so I dont understand.

```
int             get_new_file(int fd, int fd_1, t_list point)
{
  long int      nb;
  char          *buff;
  int           size_buff;
  int           len;

  nb = strtol(point.header.size, NULL, 8);
  if ((buff = malloc(sizeof(*buff) * nb + 1)) == NULL)
    return (-1);
  if ((size_buff = read(fd, buff, nb)) <= 0)
    return (-1);
  if ((len = write(fd_1, buff, nb)) <= 0)
    return (-1);
  printf("%s\n", point.header.size); /* this give me 00000000616, is this a special base ? */
  printf("%d\n", strtol(point.header.size, NULL, 8)); /* and this 398 */
  len = (len - 512) * -1;
  if ((len = read(fd, buff, len)) <= 0)
    return (-1);
  bzero(buff, nb + 1);
  return (0);
}
```

and my struct:

```
typedef struct  s_head
{
    char        name[100];
    char        mode[8];
    char        uid[8];
    char        gid[8];
    char        size[12];
    char        mtime[12];
    char        chksum[8];
    char        linkflag;
    char        linkname[100];
    char        magic[8];
    char        uname[32];
    char        gname[32];
    char        devmajor[8];
    char        devminor[8];
}               t_head;

typedef union   s_list
{
  char          tab[512];
  t_head        header;
}               t_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using libtar?

If you try use libtar, maybe you can do this.

http://www.feep.net/libtar/

Answer (score 0):

okay ive found its just strtol that convert automaticaly on base 10 so the 00000000 is on base 8